# Cannot find context with specified id with chromedriver

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm having trouble running my automated tests.

In this line:

```
Wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(findElement))
```

"`findElement`" is a element into a frame, and I'm the switch before the interacty.

I'm think that problem is caused because de Google Chrome was update for the version 63.0.3239.108, because this line not changed for 3 months.

Language: C#
Google Chrome version: 63.0.3239.108
Chromedriver version: 2.34.522940

Full StackTracke:

```
Test Name:  TrocarTecnologiaTest
Test FullName:  AutomacaoIntegra.Tests.TestTrocarTecnologia.TrocarTecnologiaTest
Test Source:    C:\git_repository\integra_test\AutomacaoIntegra\Tests\TestTrocarTecnologia.cs : line 39
Test Outcome:   Failed
Test Duration:  0:00:16,571
```

Result StackTrace:

```
em OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
   em OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   em OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElement(String mechanism, String value)
   em OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElementById(String id)
   em OpenQA.Selenium.By.<>c__DisplayClass16_0.<Id>b__0(ISearchContext context)
   em OpenQA.Selenium.By.FindElement(ISearchContext context)
   em OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElement(By by)
   em OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.ExpectedConditions.<>c__DisplayClass6_0.<ElementExists>b__0(IWebDriver driver)
   em OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.DefaultWait`1.Until[TResult](Func`2 condition)
   em AutomacaoIntegra.Extensions.Element_Extensions.EsperarElemento(IWebDriver driver, By findElement) na C:\git_repository\integra_test\AutomacaoIntegra\Extensions\Element_Extensions.cs:linha 126
   em AutomacaoIntegra.PageObjects.SolicitacaoPage.PesquisarClienteBeneficiario(String CPF) na C:\git_repository\integra_test\AutomacaoIntegra\PageObjects\SolicitacaoPage.cs:linha 117
   em AutomacaoIntegra.Tests.TestTrocarTecnologia.TrocarTecnologiaTest() na C:\git_repository\integra_test\AutomacaoIntegra\Tests\TestTrocarTecnologia.cs:linha 48
Result Message: 
System.InvalidOperationException : unknown error: unhandled inspector error: {"code":-32000,"message":"Cannot find context with specified id"}
  (Session info: chrome=63.0.3239.108)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.34.522940 (1a76f96f66e3ca7b8e57d503b4dd3bccfba87af1),platform=Windows NT 10.0.14393 x86_64)
```

Comment: Show us the code for `switch before the interacty.` and the relevant `HTML`

Answer (score 0):

The problem was because the Google Chrome updated for the 63.0.3239.108 version. I was a downgrade for the 61 version and my system is normal.